# Bounded concurrent priority queue

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, queue

I need a version of priority queue which is bounded and thread safe. In Java we have [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) which is optionally-bounded, but does not support prioritization. [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) in turn is unbounded.

Is there an out-of-the-box implementation of concurrent bounded blocking queue in Scala?

I can imagine a hand-crafted implementation using `Semaphore`, but would like to avoid reinventing a wheel.

Comment: Do you want concurrency or just thread safety? A thread safe design might rely internally on a `Semaphore`, but it won't support a high degree of concurrency.

Comment: @boneill I'd like to avoid mutually exclusion semantic of accessing a queue.

Comment: well, if you want to bound it - you need to know the current size, and without blocking - that is impossible to know; because concurrent queues size method return an approximation.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is a `MinMaxPriorityQueue` that guava has, wrapped `Queues::synchronizedQueue` that same guava provides; but this is not _concurrent_ anymore.

Comment: What about https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/BoundedPriorityQueue.html